# Can I disable the General Stats recording everything I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim as a vampire and it really bugs me that everytime my vampirism stage increases I get a spell and it records in my "Spells Learned" stat, but that stat doesn't decrease when I feed and lose the spells, basically making the stat increase meaninglessly.

Comment: I've beaten the game 5 times totally over 800 hours and I never ever even looked at that specific stat.  Why not just not look at it?